# How to add a bar on a sympy symbol?

Tags: string, latex, sympy

I want to define sympy symbols such that when I display them I get a bar on them. I tried the following one:

```
c1bar, c2bar, c3bar, ubar, alphabar = sympy.symbols(r'$\bar{c_1} \bar{c_2} \bar{c_3} \bar{u} \bar{\alpha}$')
```

I then try to display it:`display(alphabar)`  but I get: `$\displaystyle \bar{\alpha}$$`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `$` sign: SymPy automatically detect if you provided Latex syntax. So your example becomes:

```py
c1bar, c2bar, c3bar, ubar, alphabar = sympy.symbols(r'\bar{c_1} \bar{c_2} \bar{c_3} \bar{u} \bar{\alpha}')
```

Note that the bar is trying to cover both the symbol and the subscript, but it falls short. As far as I know, `\bar` only cover a single character. You can write:

```py
c1bar, c2bar, c3bar, ubar, alphabar = sympy.symbols(r'\bar{c}_1 \bar{c}_2 \bar{c}_3 \bar{u} \bar{\alpha}')
```

Or you can replace `\bar` with `\overline`:

```py
c1bar, c2bar, c3bar, ubar, alphabar = sympy.symbols(r'\overline{c_1} \overline{c_2} \overline{c_3} \overline{u} \overline{\alpha}')
```